# Angular 2 Auth data.json is not a function ERROR

Tags: angular, ionic2

In Angular 2, I want to log in using the HTTP. 
I have met all the requirements, but I'm having a problem with page redirection
Codes: 
for authservice.ts

```
 authenticate(usercreds) {
    var creds = "kullaniciAdi=" + usercreds.name + "&sifre=" + usercreds.sifre;
    var dizi = JSON.stringify({
        kullaniciAdi :usercreds.name, sifre:usercreds.sifre
    });    
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.post(this.url, dizi ).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data => {
         if(data==1){
             //console.log("Çalıştı");
             this.storeUserCredentials(data.json().token);
                resolve(true);
         }else{
             //console.log("Çalışmadı");
             resolve(false);
         }

        });
    });
```

And login.ts

```
login(usercreds) {
   // this.authservice.authenticate(usercreds);
    this.authservice.authenticate(usercreds).then(data => {
        if(data) {
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
        }else{
          this.presentToast();
        }
});}
```

[screenshot for error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnGfy.png)

Comment: can u pls post the JSON response given by the API

Comment: I only check the leading values ​​with values ​​0 and 1

Comment: `resolve(false)` doesn't return an error, it's `reject(false)`. About your problem, it comes from the fact that your back-end doesn't return a valid JSON object. You need to return a valid JSON object or not use `json()`.

Comment: Also, the `if(data == 1)` means `if(data === true)`, or more concisely `if(data)`

Comment: if your `data` variable just has value 0 and 1 then how can it have `token` property i.e it won't be an object, just a simple string. I would be able to help  if u `console.log(data)` before your `if` condition in `authenticate` function

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your service logic like this. it should work.

```
authenticate(usercreds) {
    var creds = "kullaniciAdi=" + usercreds.name + "&sifre=" + usercreds.sifre;
    let dizi = JSON.stringify({
        kullaniciAdi :usercreds.name, sifre:usercreds.sifre
    });    
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        return this.http.post(this.serverUrl, JSON.parse(creds)).map((res) => {
          if (res.status != 204) {
            Promise.resolve(res.json());
          } else {
            Promise.resolve(res);
          }
        });
    });
   }
```